# Инициализация формы по имени

Tags: vb6

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно инициализировать форму таким образом, чтобы при этом не прошел Form_Load. Сейчас это происходит таким образом

```
Dim formname as string
Dim f as vb.form
formname = "frmsample"
Set f = forms.add(formname)
f.show
```

Задача такая, показать форму уже с заданными параметрами. К примеру, есть большой отчёт с фильтрами. При способе, указанном выше, я могу только после Form_Load назначить их. Получается, что форма вызывается 2 раза.
Может есть какой-то способ сначала указать значения переменных, а потом вызвать Form_Load?
То есть надо получить эквивалент таких строк:

```
Dim f as new frmsample
f.attr1 = 1
f.attr2 = 2
f.show
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Form_Activate. В отличие от Form_Load эта функция запускается после того как форму покажут.

Comment: Если использовать Form_Activate, то форма будет наполняться каждый раз, когда фокус переходит в нее из другой... К тому же опять придется переписывать старые формы

Comment: Можете использовать глобальные переменные для обмена данных между объектами. Они сохраняют данные во время работы всего проекта и доступны для чтения и изменения из любого места.

Comment: Впринципе, сейчас так и сделано (только наоборот, через локальную переменную в форме, если не назначена, то Form_Load прерывается). Думал есть способ инициализировать форму по типу createobject